# Using the "this" object, is there an easy way (in a JS function) to get the value of a tag that was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, this

I have span element

`<span class="tag" onclick="clickTag(this)" tagType="property">`

Which calls the clickTag method

```
function clickTag(clicked){
    alert(clicked.tagType);
}
```

Is there an easy way to get the value of the `tagType` tag that is spefied in the span. I am using jQuery so if that is required, that's not a problem. Of course any other standard JS solution is welcome.

Or is there another way to specify the value of tagType and thus use it in the clickTag() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function clickTag(clicked){
    alert(clicked.getAttribute("tagType"));
}
```

I recommend you to use "data-tagType" instead which is standard in HTML5:

```
<span class="tag" onclick="clickTag(this)" data-tagType="property">


function clickTag(clicked){
    alert(clicked.getAttribute("data-tagType"));
}
```

In jQuery you can use the attr method, but I see no need for it in this context.

And as Jason Miesionczek says, you should use JavaScript to add the event listener.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I hadn't considered that there might be standard tag.

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

$(this).attr('tagType');

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".tag").click(function() {
    var element = $(this),
        tagType;

    tagType = element.attr('tagType');
    alert(tagType);
});
```

It is better to assign the click events using pure javascript as opposed to using the attributes on the tags themselves. That way if you have multiple span tags, you only have to specify the click handler once.

Comment: Yes, agreed, just testing for now.